# Hi, I am developing Bluetooth Chat app and not able to connect through blue tooth to other device

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I checked the developer site and got some help to develop the Bluetooth chat app. I'm not able to connect to other devices. I have used the UUID which was mentioned in the developer site Bluetooth chat example. I know it should be unique but I don't know how to find. Please let me know. I am using Samsung Galaxy J7.

Comment: Any help? how to connect two devices?

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth Chat sample helps how to do a similar app based on the [sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html).

> This application allows two Android devices to carry out two-way text chat over Bluetooth. It demonstrates all the fundamental Bluetooth API capabilites, such as: (1) Scanning for other Bluetooth devices (2) Querying the local Bluetooth adapter for paired Bluetooth devices (3) Establishing RFCOMM channels/sockets (4) Connecting to a remote device (5) Transfering data over Bluetooth

The sample isn't easy to learn you'll need some help by me.

---

## How to make your Bluetooth Chat app based on sample

The Bluetooth connection works in the Client and Server method, even if you're connecting 2 devices, all devices will be both Client and Server (devices  connect to others and also accept connections from others).

### The UUIDs

UUID stands for Universally Unique Identifier, your UUID must be unique, however, uniqueness isn't always guaranteed and the chances of generating a equal UUID are so low you don't need to worry about the uniqueness. If you want, google "[UUID generator](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/)" and you'll find sites like [this](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/).

Once you generated your UUID, use the same UUID for Client and Server.

### Connect to other devices

To connect to other devices, you'll have to enumerate the paired devices in the first place, the `BluetoothAdapter` contains everything for initial setup. The `android.bluetooth.*` package contains everything for your app.

`BluetoothAdapter` is a Singleton, so you can call the method `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` many times without making too much instances.

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
```

Let's assign `mBluetoothAdapter` as `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()`.

Make sure Bluetooth is on, if Bluetooth was off, let's turn on.

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
```

It will take a few seconds to turn the Bluetooth on.

#### Enumerate paired devices

Let's enumerate the paired devices, the `BluetoothDevice` contains information about a specific device, "bonded" means "paired".

```
List<BluetoothDevice> devices = new ArrayList<>();
for (BluetoothDevice device : mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()) {
    devices.add(device);
}
//Let's add the bonded devices to an ListView
MyBluetoothAdapter adapter = new MyBluetoothAdapter(this, devices);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The `MyBluetoothAdapter` is an example, you'll need to make your own `ArrayAdapter` to fit your needs.

#### Connect to device

When some item is selected, Bluetooth will connect to the device, to prevent UI freeze, the connection will be made in the background using a different Thread.

```
BluetoothDevice device = yourMethodToGetTheDevice();
ConnectThread mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
mConnectThread.start();
```

The ConnectThread code is here (I recommend to make an inner class to access parent class method):

The Bluetooth protocol that the sample uses is RFCOMM. THe `mUUID` is the UUID generated with the website mentioned.

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            mBluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connecting...");
            mBluetoothSocket.connect();
            new ConnectedThread(mBluetoothSocket);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

After the connection was established, you'll be able to send data.

### Accept connection

To accept others' connections, you'll have to start a background thread that continuously checks for a connection.

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread implements Closeable {

    private BluetoothServerSocket mBluetoothServerSocket;
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public AcceptThread(String name) {
        mBluetoothServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, mUUID);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            try {
                mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothServerSocket.accept();
                if (mBluetoothSocket != null) {
                    close();
                    new ConnectedThread(mBluetoothSocket);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        mBluetoothServerSocket.close();
        mBluetoothServerSocket = null;
        running = false;
    }

}
```

This code restricts the connection to a single device.

### Communication

Once device is connected, the `ConnectedThread` will start.

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread implements Closeable {

    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream out;
    private volatile running = true;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //The maximum amount of data to receive is 4KB, if you want to receive more data, you'll have to receive large data by chunks using while loop.
        //Usually text isn't as large as 4KB.
        byte[] data = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        while (running) {
            try {
                length = in.read(data);
                String text = new String(data, 0, length);
                Log.i(TAG, text);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                //Connection was lost
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        out.write(data);
    }

}
```

To send data, like text, use this code:

```
mConnectedThread.write("MY TEXT".getBytes());
```

To receive data, use the code inside `ConnectedThread` and handle the `String text` variable.

Comment: Thanks. But i have used the above codes but i am not able to connect to other devices. Could you please guide me in that? When i am connecting to other device its showing "Unable to connect". I don't get any error as well.  I think there is some issue with UUID, but i'm not sure.

Comment: The first time in Bluetooth programming isn't easy, I can't guide on this shortly. Try to run the sample and edit it to learn more about Bluetooth for Android.

Comment: I used the sample, can't connect. One app is waiting, the other is connecting, when I do the socket.connect on the conneting app, I always have a **Java.IO.IOException:** 'read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1'